# A question about balls-in-bins problem.

Tags: probability-theory, balls-in-bins

Drop $n$ balls into $k$ bins in an independently random way. Let $X_i$ be the number of balls in the bin with label $i$. Let $s\geq1$ be some integer. Let $Y_s=\sum_{i=1}^kX_i^s$.

It is clear that the expectation of $Y_1=n$. Are there any results in the other cases?

Comment: Tricky.  Originally, I assumed that [Linearity of Expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/) kicked in, so that $~\displaystyle \forall i, \frac{n}{k}$ is the *expected* *value* of $X_i$.  While this is true, in my ignorance of Probability Theory, this is inconclusive (to me).  That is, is the expected value of the sum equal to the sum of the expected values?  Personally, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution of $X_i$ is Binomial with parameters $n$ and $p=1/k$.  According to Wikipedia ([Binomial distribution: Higher Moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Higher_moments)),
$$E(X_i^s) = \sum_{j=0}^s S(s,j)\; n^{\underline j} \; p^j.$$
where $S(s,j)$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) and $n^{\underline j}$ is a falling factorial: $n^{\underline j} = n(n-1) \cdots (n-j+1)$.

So by linearity of expectation,
$$E(Y_s) = k \; E(X_i^s) = k \sum_{j=0}^s S(s,j)\; n^{\underline j} \; (1/k)^j.$$